# ios core data Importing large amounts of data

Tags: ios, core-data

My app needs to import objects from my web API (usually more then 5000 objects) while still interacting with the database. Currently I have the API set to return 100 objects per API request. The problem is that I have a huge performance hit. It can take > 4 seconds to import all the data. Most of this time is spent when calling the save function. I have successfully pushed the import into the background thread. However when I save the main context on the main thread at the end of each api request it can take more then 1 second to save, which pauses all scrolling, animation, etc. What can I do to put the saving of the main context into the background?

**Updated:** Here is some example code

```
-(void) importLoop:(NSManagedObjectContext*)mainContext complete:(dispatch_block_t) complete{
    [self apiRequest:^(NSArray *objects) {
        if (objects.count == 0){ // nothing to load.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), complete);
            return;
        }
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            NSManagedObjectContext* bgContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
            [bgContext setParentContext:mainContext];

            [bgContext performBlock:^{
                for (id object in objects){
                    // import data. This can take > 4 seconds
                    [bgContext save:nil]; // This can take > 1 second
                    // Note: This save merges the data to the main moc... but does not save the data to disk
                }
                [mainContext performBlock:^{
                    [mainContext save:nil]; // This can take > 1 second on main thread
                    [self importLoop:mainContext complete:complete]; // import next batch
                }];
            }];
        });
    }];
}
```

**Update:**
 According to @Wain [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22238729/1449607) I need to set up the following

mainMoc -> mainThreadMoc -> bgMoc

Where

- mainMoc has Concurrency Type NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType (this moc is used for saving to disk)
- mainThreadMoc has Concurrency Type NSMainQueueConcurrencyType and is the child of mainMoc
- bgMoc has  Concurrency Type NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType and is the child of mainThreadMoc

Ok now that I have that setup, I have the following problem... when I make changes to mainThreadMoc how do I let bgMoc know about it. I have the following function that is registered for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`

```
- (void)managedObjectContextDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *savedContext = [notification object];

    // ignore change notifications for the main MOC
    if (self.mainMoc == savedContext)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (self.mainMoc.persistentStoreCoordinator != savedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator)
    {
        // that's another database
        return;
    }
    if (savedContext == self.mainThreadMoc){
        [self.mainMoc performBlock:^{
            [self.mainMoc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
        }];
    }else if (savedContext == self.bgMoc){
        [self.mainThreadMoc performBlock:^{
            [self.mainThreadMoc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
        }];
    }
}
```

**Update:** I found that with the contexts chained as I mentioned above and if I re create the background context as I do in my initial example then things seem to be working. There is still a noticeable delay when I save the background thread (I presume this is the result of propagating the changes to the main thread). However this is a great improvement in performance.

Comment: Why not just call save on the same background thread as the import?

Comment: From what I understand when working with Core Data you should not use the same managed object context on different threads. Saving the child moc merges the data into the main moc. However to save to disk you need to save the main moc. The real problem is that I could still be interacting with the main moc during import and saving it in a different thread could cause some major issues

Comment: Is your main context directly attached to the persistent store coordinator or does it too have a parent context?

Comment: The main context is attached to the psc does not have a parent. It is the context that I use throughout the rest of my app on the main thread.

Comment: Okay, and are you absolutely certain that it is taking 1 second to `save:` the main context every 100 insertions? As in, you have configured your server to return just 100 items and you have checked it using Instruments?

Comment: Correct. It takes at least 1 second. When the DB gets bigger it can take as long as 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save to the persistent store, not necessarily from the main context.

You should have a private queue context which is parent to your main context and a background context so you can save without impacting the main thread and then merge the changes down to the main context. Main in this refers to main thread, not main ownership.

Comment: Consider using a framework like RestKit which will configure the contexts for you and help load the data in the background.

Comment: So ... I need to make a main moc that has concurrency type NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType. Then give it a child moc of concurrency type NSMainQueueConcurrencyType. Then to save I need to first save the main thread moc, then save the main moc (which is on a background thread). Well thats not complex. Furthermore if I use the main moc to do my background import will the changes be seen in the main thread moc? Or will I need to make another background moc and set its parent as the main thread moc?

Comment: Don't use the main MOC, it's just there to coordinate. You should really use a framework to manage it for you...

Comment: I updated my question. Do you have any idea how to make sure that the background moc gets updated when the main thread moc changes?

Comment: As far as changing frameworks at this point in time I am already pot committed with what I am using. However next project I will look into this. What do you recommend?

Comment: Any MOC that needs to be updated from another should observe and merge the save notification.

Comment: In my question I added a code for my attempt of keeping everything synced. It does not work.

Comment: observing and saving notifications in a parent/child context design is bad and adds additional work; it is unnecessary noise.

Comment: Can I please please request that people stop with this "just use this framework", original poster wants to find out how things work, not just load his app with another opaque framework.

Answer (score 2):

I would not have started by introducing the extra private-queue parent MOC.

At best it will slightly reduce the total amount of time spent on the main thread while increasing the total wall-clock time to complete the import.

I would also not recommend a third-party framework on top of Core Data while you are still coming to grips with the Core Data framework itself.

As for your question about processing the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, if a new `bgContext` was created temporarily for each ingestion chunk as you show in your first example, there would be no need to deal with those notifications at all because calling `save:` in a child context immediately and transparently propagates the changes to the parent.

As for the original question and example, calling `save:` should not take 1 second for 100 objects.

You should not be considering architectural changes (such as different context arrangements) until you understand *why* it's taking 1 second to save 100 objects.

Hook your app up to instruments and let *it* tell you what is taking up all the time. The answer may surprise you.

Comment: I have attached instruments to the function and the offenders are the requests to the DB (get or create type calls) and saving. Thanks for the tip about the automatic propagation of the saved data.

Comment: I had also added code to time these long running functions to verify how long they took.

Comment: Okay, so before I make a recommendation, I need one more bit of clarity. Are you simply dealing with with the accumulated time spent on the main thread or are there actual 1-second long spikes for things like `save:`?

Comment: The time spent on the main thread is to long... and I do get 1+ second long spikes for `save:`. I have done lots to reduce the overall time for the import but saving is the long pole. The duration of the import is of no concern for this project. The important thing is that the user can still interact with the UI and DB at all time. That is why I am trying to go with background threads.

Comment: Just timing the save is usually insufficient to find out where the slowness is.  There could be something UI related (for example) reacting to the save and causing the slowness.  Can you post the actual trace file? That will help a lot in finding the slowness.

Comment: I am not to concerned with decreasing the time it takes to import 100 objects. Even if the entire loop took < 0.2 seconds its still to long because the user can detect the lag while scrolling on a tableview. The solution I need is the best way to import the data on a background thread with as little impact on the main thread.

Comment: The troubling aspect here is not the total wall-clock time or even the total amount of time spent on the main thread. It's the 1+ second spikes for a `save:` of 100 objects. I agree with Marcus: seeing the raw trace would help find what's going on there.

Comment: I think trying to figure out why the save is taking so long is off topic. The initial question is about saving on a background thread. In this case the import process creates ~ 5 relationships to other objects in the DB for each object imported. So large amounts of the DB is being updated as part of the import which would explain the large spikes